# Python - Course Grader

Tags: python

I'm writing code for a course grader. The requirement are

"If the average score is greater than or equal to 70 and no single test score is below 50, then return a message of "pass".
If the average score is lower than 70 or at least one test score is below 50, then return a message of "fail"."

Once it determines the average it gives me the pass/fail statement. What am I not seeing?

So here is the code I've written:

```
def course_grader(test_scores):
    average = sum(test_scores)/len(test_scores)
    if average >= 70:
        return "pass"
    else: 
        return "fail"   

def main():
    print(course_grader([100,75,45]))     # "fail"
    print(course_grader([100,70,85]))     # "pass"
    print(course_grader([80,60,60]))      # "fail"
    print(course_grader([80,80,90,30,80]))  # "fail"
    print(course_grader([70,70,70,70,70]))  # "pass"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You don't account for the case where the average is above 70, but one or more scores are below 50.

Comment: Also you have forgotten to include in your question the actual output indicating which cases don't produce the desired output.

Comment: What happened to this part? *”And no single test score is below 50”* where’s your code for that?

Comment: Originally I was using a while statement to try and check. It then hit me that it wasn't checking the statement after it got the average.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking if the test scores are greater than or equal to 50, to do that, use the `all()` function to evaluate the condition for all test scores in one line, like this:

```
def course_grader(test_scores):
    average = sum(test_scores)/len(test_scores)
    # every ts (test score) must be greater than or equal to 50
    if average >= 70 and all(ts >= 50 for ts in test_scores):
        return "pass"
    else: 
        return "fail
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if the `min` of test scores is greater or equal to 50.

```
def course_grader(test_scores):
    average = sum(test_scores)/len(test_scores)
    if average >= 70 and min(test_scores) >= 50:
        return "pass"
    else: 
        return "fail"
```